# iOS:how to load animated webp image in webview or wkwebview

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, webview

I am unable to load animated webp image in UIWebview or WKWebview for both local webp image or any webp image url.

Url: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/fl_awebp/bored_animation.webp

I want to load webp file format in ios webview. I have local html file to implement in webview, that html file contains webp format images.

Help me to implement webp in ios webview.

Comment: Care to elaborate? Are there any errors, are any delegate methods called, how you create and load URL etc.

Comment: And what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @vinaykrishnan i find webp library it decodes webp image and showing  only non animated images, But i want to animate the webp image in webview.

Answer (score 0):

The native implementation of UIWebView on iOS doesn't support WebP. When UIWebView renders a web page that has WebP images. It shows a placeholder and nothing else.

Well, that was the case, before you found this tool. https://github.com/8BADBEEF/WebpForUIWebView

also see this if you would like to load webP images in UIImageView

You can use the Pod https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

There is it really easy to load WebP Images from the Web

With Swift:

```
SDWebImageManager.shared().loadImage(with: url, options: .highPriority, progress: nil, completed: {(resultSet) in
            YOURWEBVIEW.image = resultSet.0

        })
```

Comment: I am asking for animated webp image load in UIWebview, But i am unable to use this tool(https://github.com/8BADBEEF/WebpForUIWebView) to load animated webp image in uiwebview, its supporting only for non animated wep image.

Comment: would you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231580/error-decoding-animated-webp-ios

Comment: I try but how can i pass that info dictionary to webview

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView, WKWebView and SafariViewController only support APNG (after iOS 8), Webp and Animated WebP are not supported
[YYImage](https://github.com/ibireme/YYImage), for displaying dynamic graphs, uses a UIImageView subclass YYAnimatedImageView, inserts a CALayer directly as the rendering layer of the picture, and uses the CADisplayLink frame timer to refresh the animation frame, decodes through asynchronous threads, and some C dynamically allocates and reclaims memory to avoid very high memory usage and guarantees performance. And it automatically handles the problem of disappearing from the view and scrolling (you can still switch to RunLoopCommonMode to scroll while still showing the motion without stopping). The implementation is also very interesting. Interested people can take a look.